# Android RecyclerView doesnot appear below EditText

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a layout which has an EditText which when typed by the user should display suggestions below it.I created a RecyclerView programatically which should show the suggestion items below the EditText.But it doesn't display the RecyclerView when the user typed in the EditText. It should look like the screenshot included below:

[image]
**Java Code:
MainActivity.java:**

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
          if(charSequence.toString().equals("Taxi")){
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
              layoutParams1.setMargins(20,0,20,0);
              RecyclerView recyclerView=new RecyclerView(getContext());
              recyclerView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter());
              layoutParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,R.id.srch_qry);
              recyclerView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);

          }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

**CustomListAdapter.java:**

```
 public class CustomListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomListAdapter.Holder> {
        public String[] taxi_list={"Audi","Tavera","Chevrolet"};
        @Override
        public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cstm_lst_lyt,parent,false);
            return new Holder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {
        holder.taxi_text.setText(taxi_list[position]);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return taxi_list.length;
        }

        public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
             TextView taxi_text;
            public Holder(View itemView) {

                super(itemView);
                taxi_text=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.taxi_txt);
            }

        }
    }
```

**cstm_lst_lyt.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#10000000"
    android:id="@+id/lyt">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/taxi_txt"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="Audi"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:gravity="center|start"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like autocompletetextview?

Comment: Use `AutoCompleteTextView` for achieving this approach, No need to create `RecyclerView`.

Comment: But autocompletetextview displays the items that are similar to the character typed in the View

Comment: But here, when I type Taxi the names of taxi must be displayed below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to set layout manager for your `recyclerView`. check this :

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()))
```

then add `RecyclerView` to your `RelativeLayout`

```
RelativeLayout myRelative = (RelativeLayout )findViewById(R.id.lyt);
myRelative.addView(recyclerView);
```

Comment: I set layout manager for recyclerview, but it still doesnot display

Comment: how did you add recycler to your view ? I think you forget to add recycler to your relativelayout !! @jobin

Answer (score 0):

In your `onTextChanged()` method you create the `RecyclerView` but does not attach it to the layout via `addView()`. You should consider to add your `RecyclerView` directly in your XML layout instead of programmatically. And then change its visibility + notifying its adapter in the method `onTextChanged()`.

---

**EDIT**

Here is a example of layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/edit_text"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/text_suggestions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/edit_text"/>
```

Comment: But as you can see in the screenshot above, there is another list below the edittext

Comment: You can have more than one layout below your EditText. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you are wasting time on creating own adpter and set no need for all of this Just Use

**AutoCompleteTextView**  android view

```
 String[] fruits = {"Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date", "Grape", "Kiwi", "Mango", "Pear"};
    //Creating the instance of ArrayAdapter containing list of fruit names
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                    (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, fruits);
            //Getting the instance of AutoCompleteTextView
            AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
            actv.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character
            actv.setAdapter(adapter);//setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView
            actv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

How to use it - http://www.journaldev.com/9574/android-autocompletetextview-example-tutorial

Android code -https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html 
Best Example - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_autocompletetextview_control.htm

Be smart bro

Comment: The autocompletetextview displays string that are similar to the ones that are typed in it